# Adding data to data bound DataGridView (WinForms, C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I have 3 tables:

```
Order (OrderId, columnXY ..)
OrderItem (OrderId, ItemId, Quantity)
Item (ItemId, Name, Price)
```

The order table is bound to a `DataGridView`. On selection changed for the order dgv, an orderedItem dgv is populated like this:

```
view.GetOrderedItemDataGridView().DataSource = dataContext.OrderItemSet.Where(o => o.OrderId == orderId).Select(o => new { o.Item.Id, o.Quantity, o.Item.Price }).ToList();
```

Upon pressing an `AddItemButton`, a dialog opens to pick an item, after which the item should be added to the orderedItem dgv:

```
using (var form = new OrderItemView(dataContext.ItemSet.ToList()))
{
    if (form.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // Add selected item from OrderItemView to orderedItem dgv
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

The changes are supposed to be saved later, by clicking the SaveOrderButton, or canceled by clicking the CancelOrderButton.

```
void view_SaveOrderClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get order data
    int customerId = Convert.ToInt32(view.OrderCustomerID);
    order.CustomerId = customerId;
    order.Weight = Convert.ToDouble(view.OrderWeight);
    order.Sum = Convert.ToDecimal(view.OrderSum);
    order.Date = view.OrderDate;
    order.AddressId = dataContext.AddressSet.Where(c => c.CustomerId == customerId && c.IsDeliveryAddress == true)
                                                .Select(a => a.Id).SingleOrDefault();

    if (!orderUpdateMode)
    {
        dataContext.OrderSet.Add(order);
    }
    else
    {
        dataContext.Entry(order).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    dataContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

I can't figure out how to add a new item to the dgv, since I can't add rows directly to a data bound dgv. Also, I'm populating the dgv with an anonymous type, so I can't have a class property to use as data source to which I add the new item. Should I maybe make a new object to fill the dgv, using only the properties I want displayed? I'm retrieving the data the way I do right now so that only certain columns are added to the orderedItem dgv.

How can I solve this problem?

Cheers!

**EDIT:**
When using BindingSource I run into problems because the type I get in the OnSelectionChanged event method of the Order dgv ...

```
orderedItemsBS.DataSource = dataContext.OrderItemSet.Where(o => o.OrderId == orderId).
Select(o => new { o.Item.Id, o.Item.Name, o.Quantity, o.Item.Price }).ToList();
```

is not the same as the one I get after selecting an orderItem:

```
void view_NewOrderItemClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var form = new OrderItemView(dataContext.ItemSet.ToList()))
    {
        if (form.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            var item = new { Id = form.Item.Id, Name = form.Item.Name, Quantity = form.Quantity, Price = form.Item.Price };
            orderedItemsBS.Add(item);
            view.GetOrderedItemDataGridView().DataSource = orderedItemsBS;
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I don't want to save anything to the db in the NewOrderItemClicked method since the user might press the CancelButton after editing/adding an order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use `BindingSource` and add items to it (will automatically update `DataGridView` that is bound to ([tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24656/A-Detailed-Data-Binding-Tutorial)) or rebind data source after adding:

```
view.GetOrderedItemDataGridView().DataSource = null; 
view.GetOrderedItemDataGridView().Rows.Clear();
view.GetOrderedItemDataGridView().DataSource = dataContext.OrderItemSet.Where(o => o.OrderId == orderId).Select(o => new { o.Item.Id, o.Quantity, o.Item.Price }).ToList();
```

After edit:

First of all: do not use anonymous type, create normal class and work with it.

Second:

```
view.GetOrderedItemDataGridView().DataSource = orderedItemsBS;
```

this line is not needed, instead add this: orderedItemsBS.ResetBindings(false);

Comment: Check my edit, do not use anonymous type here and you should be fine.

Comment: Do you mean make some OrderItemDisplayObject, which contains properties for ItemId, ItemName, Quantity and Price, and then set these with the data from the OrderItem and Item tables?